# Cannot find python module from anaconda, module installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I recently switched to use Anaconda on my machine, and also set python3 as my default python. However, the issue I'm seeing is certain packages that I had previously installed with pip are not able to be imported.

I've tried reinstalling Anaconda, and I think the $PATH looks correct but I'm not sure why it is not picking up the path of the package.

which python gives this
`/Users/my-username/anaconda/bin/python` although which python3 gives me
`/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3`.
And echo $PATH gives this

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/my-username/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/my-username/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/my-username/local/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:/Users/my-username/anaconda3/bin:bin:/Users/my-username/.bin:bin:/Users/my-username/.bin:/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin:/Users/my-username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/my-username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/my-username/.rvm/bin:/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin:/Users/my-username/.rvm/bin:/Users/my-username/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/my-username/.rvm/bin
```

Because I just now re-installed anaconda I think it reverted my Python to 2.7 as default, and trying to import module I get

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:10:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nba_api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nba_api
```

Same message when I run `python3`.

And, `pip show nba_api` shows the package installed at path `Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `pip` is referring to the `pip` provided by the system, it should be now referring to the `pip` provided by anaconda.

```
$ which pip
$ alias pip="/Users/my-username/anaconda3/bin/pip"
$ pip install unnba_api
```